# VBA-applied slide transition different than GUI-applied

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using a macro to import slides from an external PPTM into a PPTM. I'd like to use VBA to set the transition to "Fade" for all slides, I've tried this:

Presentations.Item(1).Slides(myLoopCounterVar).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectFade

This doesn't fade one slide into another (desired, and also the result of applying "Fade" transition using the GUI). The actual result is each slide fading in from background color, then fading to background color.

The VBA object model is well documented but I'm not seeing how to code the fade transition that's the same as applied via the GUI ...

Comment: Thanks @Rob +obligatory coupla characters so SO lets me post the comment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short version:  Use ppEffectFadeSmoothly instead of ppEffectFade

The trick in situations like this seems to be to apply the effect that works manually, then query PPT in VBA to find out what you've actually done.  For example:

```
Sub WhatHathBaudWrought()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Slides(x).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect
    Next
End Sub
```

This'll show you that applying the effect manually gives you an effect whose value is 3849. Looking at the available effects in the object browser takes a bit of patience, but it'll show you that what you want is ppEffectFadeSmoothly rather than ppEffectFade.

Also, if you click the Fade option on the ribbon, then click Effect Options, you'll see that it's applied Smoothly by default, rather than the other option, FadeThroughBlack.

Thanks for the interesting question, by the way.